# Sorting order issue

Tags: c++, xcode, sqlite, sorting

I have an iOS app (XCode) that displays data from an SQLite database, selected using this sort of select statement:

```sql
SELECT *, rowid FROM FPLANW order by W_NAME
```

Works OK but the returned data (locations) are not sorted in true alphabetical order.  For example these is the order of some of the returned data:

```
PERTH CBD
PERTH HOSPITAL
PERTH
```

Normal sorting would place `PERTH` above `PERTH CBD`.

Is there some way I can change the database or the SELECT command to achieve this?

Comment: Is there any custom collation sequence defined for `W_NAME` column? (I mean in the `CREATE TABLE` - is there a `COLLATE` for this column defined?)

Comment: No. So is it using the standard BINARY collation?  Do I need to define a special collation sequence somehow?

Comment: Yes, it is using BINARY, but that's okay. I created a simple test case locally and for me it sorts correctly. Did you try to execute the same query against the very same database, but not under iOS, but instead under MacOSX, using it's own SQLite library? You can perhaps use the `sqlite3` command line application from MacOSX to do this test.

Answer (score 0):

User error.  The some (complex) code written by a 3rd party was manipulating the SQLite output under certain circumstances.